# Update duplicate values in vlookup (using dictionary)

Tags: vba, dictionary, vlookup

I have the below code that will do vlookup using dictionary and if a match is found then it will update the destination cell with the value present in the source sheet.

Currently the code will update only for unique values and not duplicate. I want the code to do it for duplicate value as well.

Example:
If Sheet1 col A has value 1,2,3,4,5 (source) and Sheet2 col A has value 1,2,2,2,2 (destination)..The code will update the values that sheet1 col B has into Sheet2 col B..here in this case, "2" is the only matching data..so the code will just take the text that "2" has in col B and update it in sheet2 against the FIRST "2" only and not the other "2" which is below that as those are duplicate values. The change I want to make is, it should even check for the other "2" below it.

My code:

```
Sub PassFailValidation()

    Dim cl As Range, Dic As Object

    Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary"): Dic.CompareMode = vbTextCompare

        With Sheets("Latency")
        For Each cl In .Range("B2:B" & .Cells(.Rows.count, "C").End(xlUp).Row)
            Dic.Item(cl.Value) = cl.Row
        Next cl
    End With

     With Sheets("Test")
        For Each cl In .Range("A2:A" & .Cells(.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
            If Dic.Exists(cl.Value) Then
                Sheets("Latency").Cells(Dic(cl.Value), 15) = cl.Offset(, 1) '<--| write the values
                Dic.Remove (cl.Value)
            End If
        Next cl
    End With

 End Sub
```

Comment: this question has so much similarity that wit this one that it could be http://stackoverflow.com/q/41658256/3961708 marked as duplicate. Any how, if you want to keep duplicates then don't remove the dictionary item

Comment: Can you please post the same as answer so that I can mark that as an answer and close this question? @cyboashu

Comment: Don't worry, if it resolved your issue,then its all good. Cheers!!

Comment: Thank you @cyboashu